# powershell Button only works one time

Tags: function, variables, powershell, foreach, powershell-2.0

I was trying to create a Website "IsitUP" Checker to determine if a group of websites were up.

-My network does not support ICMP outbound so Ping/Test Connection are out

-I'm using Powershell v2 so Web-RequestGet is out as well

-I decided to strings the page and then compare the line to check if up.

So far so good.

Now i just want to be able to Refresh the results and provide a time stamp when I click the button. My issue now is that the foreach statement used the same variable for each sites status and it won't reset all the variables. So when the refresh button is pushed only the last site checked is refreshed.

So my question is How do i either 
A) set a variable using the foreach statement for a new object each time?
b) reset all of the same variable on the whole form?

```
##This hides the powershell cmd pmompt

PowerShell.exe -windowstyle hidden {

## This is the APAN DNS array 
$sites = "https://chat.apan.org","https://connect.apan.org","https://m.apan.org","https://mail.apan.org","https://www.apan.org"
$SitelocH = 10
$sitelocW = 10
$statlocH = 10
$statlocW = 150
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 

$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$objForm.Text = "APAN GO!"
$objForm.Opacity = (.95)
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,200) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "WindowsDefaultLocation"
## APAN ICON

$RefreshButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$RefreshButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,130)
$RefreshButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$RefreshButton.Text = "Refresh"
$RefreshButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Controls.remove($STAT)})
$RefreshButton.Add_Click({Refresh})
$objForm.Controls.Add($RefreshButton)



foreach ($site in $sites)

{ 
## This is going to call a string for each site, then it is going to count the   characters 
$StatDescrption = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString($site) | Measure-Object -line |Select-Object -ExpandProperty lines
if ($StatDescrption -ge 1) {$StatDescrption = "OK!"} else {$StatDescrption ="DOWN"}




$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($sitelocW,$sitelocH)  
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(140,15)
$objLabel.Text = $site
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

$sitelocH1 = $SitelocH +20
$sitelocH = $sitelocH1




$STAT= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$STAT.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($statlocW,$statlocH)  
$STAT.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,20)
$STAT.ForeColor ="green"
$STAT.Text = $StatDescrption
$objForm.Controls.Add($STAT)  

$statlocH1 = $statlocH +20
$statlocH = $statlocH1

}



Function Refresh { 

$statlocH = 10


foreach ($site in $sites) { 

## This is going to call a string for each site, then it is going to count the    characters 
$StatDescrption = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString($site) | Measure-Object -line |Select-Object -ExpandProperty lines
if ($StatDescrption -ge 1) {$StatDescrption = "OK!!"} else {$StatDescrption ="DOWN"}

$STAT.Refresh

$STAT = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$STAT.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($statlocW,$statlocH)  
$STAT.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,20)
$STAT.ForeColor ="green"
$STAT.Text = $StatDescrption
$objForm.Controls.Add($STAT)  

$statlocH1 = $statlocH +20
$statlocH = $statlocH1

$time.Refresh

$TIME= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$TIME.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(40,110)  
$TIME.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,20)
$TIME.Text = Get-Date
$objForm.Controls.Add($TIME)  


}}


$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with removing the controls. `$RefreshButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Controls.remove($STAT)})` only removes the last label because that's what $STAT is set to.

Putting in `$objform.controls | foreach-object {if ($_.Tag -eq "STAT") {$objform.controls.remove($_)}}` at the start of your Refresh function and `$STAT.Tag = "STAT"` in the stat label creation removes all the status labels which are then correctly replaced.